# Finding the sum of dollars linked to a single entry multiple times in another column

Tags: sum, ssms

I have a table with columns labeled procedure_code and amt_paid and several others but those 2 are the only ones that matter with what I'm trying to do. In the procedure_code column there may be 100's of entries of the same surgical procedure code because the dollar amounts paid may vary. I've tried the following query but it keep getting returns of each entry of the code and the dollar amounts paid as separate rows:

```
select procedure_code,count(procedure_code) as number_times_reported,
       sum(amt_paid) as total_dollars from table group by procedure_code, amt_paid;
```

Can somebody please point me in the right direction so that the results are 1 procedure code, the number of times it occurred and the sum of ALL dollars associated with that procedure code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the amt_paid column from the "group by". Should be as follows:

```
select procedure_code, 
count(procedure_code) as number_times_reported, 
sum(amt_paid) as total_dollars from table 
group by procedure_code;
```